# ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: debian, ssh

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 178.xxx.xxx.xxx [178.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/orangetux/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/orangetux/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/orangetux/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/orangetux/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/orangetux/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/orangetux/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Via an admin panel I can access the logs and I see:

```
Mar  8 20:32:10 vmi11458 sshd[2334]: Set /proc/self/oom_adj to 0
Mar  8 20:32:10 vmi11458 sshd[2334]: refused connect from 82.xxx.xxx.xxx (82.xxx.xxx.xxx)
```

I've stopped the DenyHosts service. But I still cannot log in.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By stopping the denyhosts service, you prevent new entries from being created in `/etc/hosts.deny`, but entries that are already there remain. You will need manually remove the IP from the `hosts.deny` folder. To prevent the IP from being added again, you need to whitelist it in the `allowed-hosts` file.

Answer (score 0):

To debug this issue, check the following things:

1. Please double-check that the permission of your `.ssh` directory `700` and permissions of your `.ssh/authorized_keys` file must be `600`.
2. Check the logs `/var/secure/logs`  for knowing reason of connection close.

Comment: I've checked that already. The problem was that my IP appeared in the `host.deny`